# Modify date string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some events that pulls its date like the following:

*20th June 10am - 5th September 10pm*

*28th September noon - 4pm*

I've not control of what it returns, so I need to remove it via javascript

I need to remove the time and replace the months with 3 character version, like the below:

20th Jun - 5th Sep

I've started doing it but I don't know how to remove the time, because it could be either formatted with AM/PM or MIDNIGHT/NOON

[This is what I've done so far](https://codepen.io/palomatiessen/pen/dybzMQO?editors=0012):

```
var dateExample = '2nd August 9am - 27th September midnight';
function trimDate(date){
  const dateArray = date.split(' ');
  var months = [['January', 'Jan'], ['February', 'Feb'], ['March', 'Mar'], ['April', 'Apr'], ['May', 'May'], ['June', 'Jun'], ['July', 'Jul'], ['August', 'Aug'], ['September', 'Sep'], ['October', 'Oct'], ['November', 'Nov'], ['December', 'Dec']];

  for (let x = 0; x < months.length; x++){
    let i = dateArray.findIndex(d => d === months[x][0]);
    if (i > -1) dateArray.splice(i, 1, months[x][1]);
  }
  console.log(dateArray.join(' '));
}

trimDate(dateExample);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should be possible with a single regex:

```js
const dateExamples = [
  '2nd August 9am - 27th September midnight',
  '20th June 10am - 5th September 10pm',
  '2nd August noon - 27th September midnight'
]
const regex = /[0-9]{1,2}[ndrths]{2}[\s]{1}[\w]{3}/g
dateExamples.forEach(dateExample => console.log(dateExample.match(regex).join(' - ')))
```

Comment: Much better than my weak attempt

Comment: ha, yours was helpful actually!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the dates can be done much simpler using regex:

```js
var dateExample = '2nd August 9am - 27th September midnight';
var re = /January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December/gi;
var replaced = dateExample.replace(re, m => m.substring(0,3));
console.log(replaced)
```

You could use a similar trick for the times, the regex might be a bit more complex:

```js
var dateExample = '2nd August 9am- 27th September midnight';
var datesRegex = /January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December/gi;


var timesRegex = /\w*([0-9]{1,2}(am|pm|AM|PM))|(noon|midnight)\w*/gi
var replaced = dateExample.replace(datesRegex, m => m.substring(0,3))
                           .replace(timesRegex,'');
console.log(replaced)
```

Putting it all together

```js
function clean(input){

  var datesRegex = /January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December/gi;
  var timesRegex = /\w*([0-9]{1,2}(am|pm|AM|PM)\w*)|(noon|midnight)/gi
  return input.replace(datesRegex, m => m.substring(0,3))
                             .replace(timesRegex,'');
}

// test cases
console.log(clean("20th June 10am - 5th September 10pm"));
console.log(clean("2nd August 9am - 27th September midnight"));
console.log(clean("2nd August noon - 27th September midnight"));
```

Comment: this is a great answer!